# Should I use sessionStorage and if so, how?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, dynamic, sessionstorage

I have built a simple task app that allows you to add different tasks. It works fine. I am not sure what is the best approach however to retain the data/HTML once the page is refreshed. I have heard of HTML5 session/localStorage but I am not sure if this would be the best method to use in this situation. Also, I would need help making this work if sessionStorage was a good choice.

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var generateBtn = document.getElementById("generate");
  generateBtn.onclick = addTask;

  var tasksWrapper = document.getElementById("tasksWrapper");
  var taskDesc = document.getElementById("taskDesc");
}

var taskId = 0;
var taskBarArray = [];

function addTask() {

  taskId++;

  var taskBar = document.createElement("div");
  var taskBarInput = document.createElement("input");
  var taskBarDeleteBtn = document.createElement("input");

  taskBar.setAttribute("id", taskId);
  taskBar.setAttribute("class", "taskBar");

  taskBarInput.setAttribute("class", "taskDesc");
  taskBarInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  taskBarInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter task");

  function rmPlaceholder() {
    taskBarInput.removeAttribute("placeholder", "Enter task");
  }

  function addPlaceholder() {
    taskBarInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter task");
  }

  taskBarInput.onfocus = rmPlaceholder;
  taskBarInput.onblur = addPlaceholder;

  taskBarInput.setAttribute("name", "taskDesc");
  taskBarInput.setAttribute("value", taskDesc.value);

  taskBarDeleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "deleteBtn");
  taskBarDeleteBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  taskBarDeleteBtn.setAttribute("value", "x");

  var addTaskBar = tasksWrapper.appendChild(taskBar);

  var targetTaskId = document.getElementById(taskId);

  var addTaskBarInput = targetTaskId.appendChild(taskBarInput);
  var AddTaskBarDeleteBtn = targetTaskId.appendChild(taskBarDeleteBtn);

  taskBarArray.push(taskBar);

  taskDesc.value = "";
  taskBarDeleteBtn.onclick = removeTask;

  function removeTask(e) {
    taskBarDeleteBtn = e.target;

    tasksWrapper.removeChild(taskBar);
    taskBarArray.pop(e);

    if (taskBarArray.length < 1) {
      taskId = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  #main_wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 528px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .taskBar {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333230;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .taskDesc {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .deleteBtn {
    margin: 6px 6px 0 0;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 32px;
    background: #8F0A09;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-color: #000;
    float: right;
    outline: none;
  }
  #header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #taskDesc {
    padding: 2px 0;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #generate {
    padding: 5px 83px;
    background: #82CC12;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
  }
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #4C4B48;
  }
  ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #4C4B48;
  }
  :-ms-placeholder {
    color: #4C4B48;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <input type="text" id="taskDesc"></input>
    <input type="button" id="generate" value="Add task">
  </div>
  <div id="tasksWrapper">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I would use localStorage, it will be remembered even after the session has timed out. A session is probably ended if the user restarts their browser.

The only problems I see with localStorage is the 10 MB size limit on desktops (2 MB om mobile devices I think), and that it's not easy enough to get data from localStorage to the server. But localStorage would be a perfect fit for a TODO app with simple items.